# JavaScript Canvas: functions called asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, canvas

I’m new to working with HTML5 canvas, but I have encountered an issue I have never seen mentioned.

Suppose I have the following code (assuming existing `canvas` and `context` variables):

```
function test() {
    context.fillStyle='red';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
}
test();
function test() {
    context.fillStyle='green';
    context.fillRect(0, 40, 40, 40);
}
test();
```

I find that *both* the rectangles will be the second colour, and the actual location is also wrong.

If I change the second function name to something else and call that instead:

```
function test() {
    context.fillStyle='red';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
}
test();
function test2() {
    context.fillStyle='green';
    context.fillRect(0, 40, 40, 40);
}
test2();
```

… then it works as intended. This indicates that the drawing functions must be asynchronous, and so the second version of `test()` starts to interfere with the first.

The question is:

- is this the correct interpretation of what is happening?
- what can I do, apart from renaming functions, to run the first example synchronously?

Thanks

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted.

Comment: Nothing related with asyncronous calls. @Xufox is right, hoisting is acting

Comment: [this is the reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: That was fast! Damn, you’re right, and I should have known all along. setting `test=function() { … }` fixed it. Could you put your comment in the form of an answer?